# Using Muller's method to find ALL roots ( real and complex) with three initial guesses.

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods

Is there any way to find all complex and real roots of a third-degree polynomial using only Muller's equation using initial guesses:

$x_0=0.6,x_1=0.7,x_2=0.8,  ε_s=0.01$%

$f(x)=x^3 - x^2+3x-2 $

I have found the real root after two iterations $x_r=0.71511$

How can I find the other two complex roots without using MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps factorize the polynomial
$$f(x) = (x-x_r)(x^2-(x_r+1)x + \frac{2}{x_r})$$

Comment: Which point discard for each iterations in Muller's method?

Comment: Which point discard for each iterations in Muller's method?

Comment: Thank you, that was a brilliant idea to do.  However, what can I do if I have a higher-degree polo nominal function? Is there anyway to determine another three initial guesses that are close to one of the complex roots?

Comment: $x_0$ is the discarded point for each iteration.